# Regular Expression library that maintains state, takes input character by character and returns true whenever match is found

Tags: c++, c, regex

I am looking for a library that does regular expression search in text. The constraint i have is that the text is huge and has several control characters in between them. So I can not pass  the whole text to the library. I have something like getnextcharacter which returns valid characters after skipping the control characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions of the C++11 [Regex Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) accept iterators. So if you write an iterator for your text that skips the special characters, you'll be well.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ I recommend boost Xpressive:
 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/xpressive.html

For C pcre might be in order:
 http://www.pcre.org/

About your constraint, you might try to wrap that logic into an input iterator for Xpressive.